# Convert list of dictionaries into list of sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dictionaries within a list like this:

```
[{'market': 'singapore', 'abbreviation': 'sg', 'indexId': 'STI', 'indexName': 'STRAITS TIMES INDEX'}, {'market': 'thailand', 'abbreviation': 'th', 'indexId': 'SET100', 'indexName': 'SET100 INDEX'}, {'market': 'turkey', 'abbreviation': 'tr', 'indexId': 'XUTEK', 'indexName': 'BIST TEKNOLOJI'}, {'market': 'thailand', 'abbreviation': 'th', 'indexId': 'SET50', 'indexName': 'SET50 INDEX'}]
```

The desired results should look like this

```
[{'market', 'singapore', 'abbreviation', 'sg', 'indexId', 'STI', 'indexName', 'STRAITS TIMES INDEX'}, {'market', 'thailand', 'abbreviation', 'th', 'indexId', 'SET100', 'indexName', 'SET100 INDEX'}, {'market', 'turkey', 'abbreviation', 'tr', 'indexId', 'XUTEK', 'indexName', 'BIST TEKNOLOJI'}, {'market', 'thailand', 'abbreviation': 'th', 'indexId', 'SET50', 'indexName', 'SET50 INDEX'}]
```

How can I possibly remove the ":" within this list of dictionaries? I know I can use the `re.sub()` function, but I don't know how to apply it in this scenario.

Comment: What you have appears to look like a JSON, which you could use instead of a list of strings. This way you won't get duplicate "market",  "abbreviation" etc.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea. Why do you want this?

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea. You *might* be able to do it using `re.sub()` (by converting your data to its string representation) but lets say "nobody does that". Regex is powerful tool to deal with other problems. Here better not using it.

You can do the following:

```py
res = [{*d.keys(), *d.values()} for d in lst]
print(res)
```

Basically you unpack both `.keys()` and `.values()` iterators into a set. Final result is a set.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a set in the first form. That's a dictionary. To put all `dict`'s keys and values into a set you can do it like this:

```py
>>> [set(list(i.keys()) + list(i.values())) for i in x]
[{'singapore', 'abbreviation', 'sg', 'STI', 'STRAITS TIMES INDEX', 'indexId', 'indexName', 'market'}, {'th', 'abbreviation', 'SET100 INDEX', 'thailand', 'indexId', 'SET100', 'indexName', 'market'}, {'BIST TEKNOLOJI', 'market', 'abbreviation', 'indexId', 'tr', 'XUTEK', 'indexName', 'turkey'}, {'th', 'SET50 INDEX', 'abbreviation', 'thailand', 'indexId', 'indexName', 'SET50', 'market'}]
```

Where `x` is your list.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are not part of a string, they are formatting provided by the `print()` function. It seems that you want to convert a list of dictionaries into a list of lists. You can do that like this with a list comprehension:

```
lst = [{'market': 'singapore', 'abbreviation': 'sg', 'indexId': 'STI', 'indexName': 'STRAITS TIMES INDEX'}, {'market': 'thailand', 'abbreviation': 'th', 'indexId': 'SET100', 'indexName': 'SET100 INDEX'}, {'market': 'turkey', 'abbreviation': 'tr', 'indexId': 'XUTEK', 'indexName': 'BIST TEKNOLOJI'}, {'market': 'thailand', 'abbreviation': 'th', 'indexId': 'SET50', 'indexName': 'SET50 INDEX'}]

res = [[item for sublist in dct.items() for item in sublist] for dct in lst]
print(res)
```

Alternatively, you can use this for a list of sets:

```
lst = [{'market': 'singapore', 'abbreviation': 'sg', 'indexId': 'STI', 'indexName': 'STRAITS TIMES INDEX'}, {'market': 'thailand', 'abbreviation': 'th', 'indexId': 'SET100', 'indexName': 'SET100 INDEX'}, {'market': 'turkey', 'abbreviation': 'tr', 'indexId': 'XUTEK', 'indexName': 'BIST TEKNOLOJI'}, {'market': 'thailand', 'abbreviation': 'th', 'indexId': 'SET50', 'indexName': 'SET50 INDEX'}]

res = [set([item for sublist in dct.items() for item in sublist]) for dct in lst]
print(res)
```